# Cast or convert List<T?> to List<T>?

Tags: kotlin, casting, iterable

I'm looking for a convenient way to safely cast a `List<T?>` to `List<T>?` (or, more generically, `Iterable<T?>` to `Iterable<T>?`) without filtering any elements.

In other words, take the list if all elements are not null.

In Swift I can do this:

```swift
let a: [Int?] = [1, nil, 3]
let b: [Int?] = [1, 2, 3]

let aa = a as? [Int] // nil
let bb = b as? [Int] // [1, 2, 3]
```

In Kotlin, the similarly looking code just does an unchecked cast and does not result in `aa` being `null`:

```
val a = listOf<Int?>(1, null, 3)
val b = listOf<Int?>(1, 2, 3)

val aa = a as? List<Int> // [1, null, 3]
val bb = b as? List<Int> // [1, 2, 3]
```

Thus, I'm looking for a method like this:

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
fun <T : Any> Iterable<T?>.takeIfAllNotNull(): Iterable<T>? =
    takeIf { all { el -> el != null } } as? Iterable<T>
```

With that I can write my code as follows:

```
val a = listOf<Int?>(1, null, 3)
val b = listOf<Int?>(1, 2, 3)

val aa = a.takeIfAllNotNull() // null
val bb = b.takeIfAllNotNull() // [1, 2, 3]
```

I must be missing something here. Doesn't the standard library have such a method?

Comment: So you are asking for a Kotlin solution? In that case you should *not* tag the question with [swift] – at least that is how I understand it from https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316809/1187415 on Meta.

Comment: `val aa = a as? List<Int> // [1, null, 3]` looks like a bug

Comment: it looks like a bug, but the compiler warns about an unsafe cast which is ignored in the question. Ignoring unsafe casts can lead to types being incorrect at runtime.

Comment: @MartinR, [swift] removed. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no build-in function but you can combine `filterNotNull` and `takeIf` to get the desired behaviour:

```
val a: List<Int?> = listOf(1, null, 3)
val aa: List<Int>? = a.filterNotNull().takeIf { it.size == a.size }
```

--

Edit: as per @DrawnRacoon's suggestion it would be faster to use just takeIf:

```
val aa: List<Int>? = a.takeIf { null !in a } as List<Int>
```

This does not create an intermediate List and it short circuits when it finds a null. It does require an unsafe cast to force the compiler to change the type.

Extracted in an extension function it would look like this:

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
fun <T> Iterable<T?>.takeIfAllNotNull(): Iterable<T>? {
    return takeIf { null !in this } as? Iterable<T>
}
```

---

It seems we have arrived back at your original proposal. So maybe the answer should have just been:

**No**, you are not missing anything.
There is no method in the standard library for this exact behaviour.

---

To touch what is going on in the question:
It has to do with generics erosion. In runtime there are no generics so the cast is just `List` to `List` which always succeeds, and it returns the original object.
The compiler will correctly warn you about an unsafe cast. Ignoring this warning may lead to incorrect types at runtime:

```
val a = listOf(1, null, 3)     
val aa = a as? List<Int> // unsafe cast List<Int?> to List<Int> 
// aa is now List<Int> but contains a null
```

You are casting `List<Int?>` to `List<Int>` but the runtime cannot differentiate these types.
To cast this safely, somewhere we actually have to check the contents of the list. It's better to do that explicitly so it's clear what's going on, hence the extra function calls in our examples.

Comment: This is a good approach. Could make an extension function as well. `fun <T> List<T?>.takeIfAllNotNull(): List<T>? = this.filterNotNull().takeIf { it.size == this.size }`

Comment: You don't need to filter it, just `val aa = a.takeIf { null !in it }`

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon yes that would actually be much faster. Only you would have to manually cast it to List<T>, which the compiler treats as an unsafe cast even though it is perfectly safe.

Comment: oh, yes, smart casting doesn't work here. Also, there is same function in the question

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the explanation. The function that I came up with is basically the solution. Didn't know about `null !in this`, which is much shorter than `all { el -> el != null }`.